# Are static variables guaranteed to be in order if I take its address?

Tags: c++, variables, static, alignment, size

I was wondering, if I take the address of a totally static class, am I guaranteed for its members to be aligned in the right order? I guess this goes also for a group of variables defined in global scope.

```
struct Buffer1
{
    static float val1;
    static float val2;
};

void readBuffer(void* buffer){ /*Do something*/}

int main()
{
// Sending the buffer
    readBuffer(&Buffer1);               // Type name is not allowed
    readBuffer(&Buffer1::val1);         // Does work, wondering if data will be correct

    return 0;
}
```

Also, is there a way of taking the size of a group of static or global variables? Like:

```
// Getting the size of the buffer
    size_t sizeOfBuffer = sizeof(Buffer1);  // Wrong size, doesn't measure static members
    sizeOfBuffer = sizeof(Buffer1::val1) + sizeof(Buffer1::val2);   // Does work but doesn't account for data padding/alignment, and is also tedious to change
```

I know in this case it's much better to work with instantiating the class, but I'm curious about these two questions. Thanks.

Comment: Just put those variables in a struct

Comment: You'll also run up against structure padding issues. Can't you do `struct Buffer1 { float val1, val2; }; static Buffer1 buffer1;` instead so you can avoid at least the `sizeof` problem.

Comment: @Ken Y-N Yes, definitely, that's currently how I have it. I was just wondering, I'm learning about the ins and outs of the language and was trying to see what I could do with a static struct.

Answer (score 2):

No, the C++ standard does not specify the order of objects in memory, in static scope.

Neither does the C++ standard guarantee the relative order of class members, either.

Comment: C++11 does guarantee that non static class data members within the same access control are ordered sequentially in memory.

Comment: @doug Interesting. Sorry, I'm not familiar with "same access control". Does that mean in the same area? So listed consecutively in a class, or consecutively in global space?

Comment: @TitoneMaurice : declared variables separated by private, public, protected are not required to be consecutive by the standard. Variables are ordered consecutively between these access specifiers though possibly with padding.